# How to launch iPhone app (using Phonegap) on iTunes

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

How do I launch an iPhone app (using Phonegap) on iTunes?

What are the requirements to launch an app on iTunes?
We already have a developer certificate.

Comment: It's no different than a non-PhoneGap app. You build the app, you submit it to Apple, you wait for it to be reviewed.

Answer (score -1):

To get an app onto the iTunes (Apple) App Store, you need to go through iTunesConnect:

http://developer.apple.com/support/resources/itunes-connect.html

I am not sure I know what you mean by Phonegap.

Comment: PhoneGap is one of those "I wrap your stuff in a UIWebView to make it look native" frameworks that lets you create native-like Apps with HTML/CSS/JavaScript ;-)

Comment: Ugh.  Thankfully, it still has to go through iTunesConnect.

Comment: Thanks for your sincere help.